# InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am building a .net Core + React application and using Azure DevOps Pipelines for the CICD process. 
The application runs locally in release and debugs both configurations. I have an IIS server up and running in my own VM. When I tried to deploy it using Azure Pipelines it gives me below Error message. Before it was working perfectly fine but all of a sudden it's showing me that error. Can anyone help me out?

[Please look into the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFF04.png)

Comment: Hi @bispul Did you check out the Path Environment Variables under System Variables as below answer mentioned. How was it going now?

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing this error when on my Azure App Service I have the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set to Development. I am suspicious that this is caused by the following if statement in the React template Startup.cs:

```
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment()) 
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```

I do not think we need to start the React Development server in Azure.

My solution would be either to comment out the if statement in the Startup.cs or change the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT setting to something else than Development.

Answer (score 1):

The error output was 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Above error in the screenshot indicates the npm command file cannot be found in the system path. It is probably because the azure agent logs into your VM with a build service account when deploying the application, and the npm command file is not in the Environment Variables Path for the build service account.

You can log into your VM and check if the npm command file is in the Path Environment Variables under **System Variables**(not User variables), so that it will be accessible to all users. If not, just add `;C:\Program Files\nodejs\` (path of your nodejs installed directory) to the Path Environment Variable.

System->Advanced system settings-->Environment Variable--->System Variables
[image]

If the issue persists, you can try upgrading/downgrading the node.js installed on VM. For troubleshooting you can check if there is any changes to your VM recently.

Hope above helps!